# Retrieving LIS file data in python

Tags: python, lis

I have some *.lis (and *.dis) files to open and parse in python.

I cannot understand their structure so can't see how pragmatically you can open and output the data reliably.

Anyone any ideas about how to comprehend the .lis file structure so I can do this? Are there any Python tools to do this that anyone is aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and here is how I solved it.

For LIS files you can use [https://pypi.org/project/TotalDepth/]. 
The package is very nicely structured but it comes with complexity in finding the right pieces of data that you require. Particularly from the header information. 
TotalDepth package also extracts data from LAS files which are much easier to understand how they work.

For DLIS files, well, these are much more convoluted than LIS to put it shortly, however this package [https://pypi.org/project/dlispy/] is wonderful and I have used it many times.

If you would like to succeed in understanding how data extraction from these types of files works please try to read the documentation for RP66 [http://w3.energistics.org/rp66/v1/Toc/main.html] and LIS79 [http://w3.energistics.org/LIS/lis-79.pdf].

A word of caution, the documents are very dull to read and understand but it will help you understand how data is structured and where to find each specific information from them.

Best of luck :)